# Looping through multiple arrays to concatenate

Tags: c#

I have 3 arrays. Two are arrays of strings and one is of date/time. I pulled all 3 from user input. Each array is always going to have the same exact amount of entries, so what I want to do is be able to loop through all 3 at once to make a string.

I was trying:

```
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        // select

        foreach (string line in array1)
        {
            foreach (string lines in array2)
            {
                foreach (DateTime date in datearray1)
                {
                    results.Add("select * from table1 d, table2 c where d.specheader = c.specheader and c.true_false = true and d.number = " + lines.ToString() + " and d.date = '" + date.ToShortDateString() + "' and d.specnum like '%" + line.ToString() + "';");                        
                }
            }
        }

        results.ToArray();
        foreach (string line in results)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(line);
        }
```

The user types in information into 3 boxes and I'm just trying to concatenate sql statements based on the input. However when I tried doing it this way it looped through 6 times when I had only 2 entries. Is there a way to concatenate a string using all 3 arrays at the same time (so like entry 1 of array 1, entry 1 of array 2, entry 1 of array 3 - Then move on to creating the next string, entry 2 of array 1, entry 2 of array 2, entry 2 of array 3, etc.)

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do not use string concatenation with SQL statements in your C# code. Read up on SQL injection.

Comment: So I read up on SQLInjection. The resulting SQL queries will be shown in a window just for myself to be able to copy. I am just trying to save time as there's generally a lot of these records. However I'm just going to be copying the text (which will be the resulting SQL command) and pasting it to use later on. Am I still at risk in that sense? Because I will be able to see the command before it's run, it's not automated.

Answer (score 2):

As the first commenter said (Yuck) don't use concatenation of strings into your SQL like that. You will want to setup an SQL Command and then pass in parameters.

That is however beside the point as you are asking about rolling together data from multiple arrays into 1 string.

Iterate through one of the arrays, If they all have the same count you will neatly get the data in one.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    results.Add(string.format("Hello you! {0} , {1}, {2}", array1[i], array2[i], datearray[i])
}
```

This will get your desired result but your code is open to vulnerabilities as it stands. You need to change your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Because your loops are nested, you're getting every value of `array2` combined with every value in `array1` (and similarly with `datearray1`. That's why you get too many results.

Your loops would work as intended like this (I've used similar local variables to avoid retyping the `results.Add` line, and to make clear how the code differs from yours):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    string line = array1[i];
    string lines = array2[i];
    DateTime date = datearray1[i];

    results.Add("select * from table1 d, table2 c where d.specheader = c.specheader and c.true_false = true and d.number = " + lines.ToString() + " and d.date = '" + date.ToShortDateString() + "' and d.specnum like '%" + line.ToString() + "';");                        
}
```

As a side-note: building a database query in this manner is inefficent and very insecure (try reading up on "Sql Injection" to understand why). You would see better results if you used a stored procedure instead.

Comment: Or you could use a parameterized SqlCommand - not just a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

if number of entries are going to be same for all you can simple do a for loop

```
                for (int 1 = 0; i < datearray1.length; i++)
                {
                    results.Add("select * from table1 d, table2 c 
                                 where d.specheader = c.specheader and c.true_false = true
                                 and d.number = " + array2[i].ToString() + " 
                                 and d.date = '" + datearray1[i].ToShortDateString() + "'
                                 and d.specnum like '%" + array1[i].ToString() + "';");                        
                }
```